# Class object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, json, api

I am trying to order a list user data, in the form of dictionaries, which contains random user data generated by an API. I am using .get to pull the date of birth (dob) from the dictionaries within the list to organize the data, but I keep getting the error "AttributeError: 'randomuser' object has no attribute 'get'". Since it seems that the problem is coming from the interaction with the 'randomuser' class, I tried side-stepping the class by placing the user data directing into a user dictionary in the main program loop, and this seemed to work. But as I am trying to learn OOP, any help in explaining where I am going wrong with the 'randomuser' class is appreciated! Cheers!

```
import requests
import json


class randomuser(object):
    
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, gender, username, password, dob) -> None:
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.gender = gender
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.dob = dob
        self.user_dict = {
            "firstname": self.firstname,
            "lastname": self.lastname,
            "gender": self.gender,
            "username": self.username,
            "password": self.password,
            "dob": self.dob
        }

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.user_dict)

""" 

create a 10 user list with 5 men and 5 women 
"""

male = 0
female = 0
user_list = []
while male < 5 or female < 5:

    response = requests.get("https://randomuser.me/api/")   # pulls JSON object from API
    user = json.loads(response.text)['results'][0]   # converst to Python dictionary
    firstname = user['name']["first"]
    lastname = user['name']["last"]
    gender = user['gender']
    username = user['login']['username']
    password = user['login']['password']
    dob = user['dob']['date']
    
    new_user = randomuser(firstname, lastname, gender, username, password, dob)

    if gender == 'male' and male < 5:
        male += 1
        user_list.append(new_user)
    elif gender == 'female' and female < 5:
        female += 1
        user_list.append(new_user)

"""

sort user list by DOB
"""

user_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.get('dob'))
print(user_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of classes, not dictionaries, so your lambda argument is a class without a `get` function

To sort by `dob` attribute, you'd do this

```
user_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.dob)
```

I'd also suggest using [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) or a `NamedTuple` rather than define `user_dict`, as you're only using this for printing

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer! I looked into dataclasses a bit, looks like its a way to more easily write out instance attributes. What advantage would dataclasses give me in this particular example (sorry for my ignorance)? But you response helped me realize the issue. I filled the list with new_user.user_dict which solved the problem.

Comment: With data classes, you wouldn't need to define the repr function, and there's really no need to carry around an extra dictionary that'll not get updated as you might change the actual class attributes